# What is the reason for "UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:" python?

Tags: python, nlp, data-analysis, word2vec

I am doing data analysis using python and word2vec for tweets to see the positive and negative tweets but I am getting this error when running the following part of the code.
I used this code form GitHub :
https://github.com/AI-Trends/NLP-Tutorial/blob/master/Twitter_Sentiment_Analysis.ipynb

the only thing I did is changed the dataset only.
My datasets contain Arabic tweets instead of English ones.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.layers as layers
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
from keras.layers import Input,Embedding,Dense,Flatten
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

epochs = 25
batch_size = 1024
loss = "binary_crossentropy"
optimizer = "adam"
metrics = ["accuracy"]

from keras import models

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),
            ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]

# Build neural network
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(200,)))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics= metrics)
model.fit(xtrain_w2v,ytrain,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size,callbacks=callbacks,validation_data=(xvalid_w2v,yvalid))


predictions = model.predict(xvalid_w2v)
predictions = [0 if i<0.5 else 1 for i in predictions]

f1_score(yvalid, predictions)
# print("Accuracy: ",accuracy_score(ytrain,predictions))
# print("Classification Report: ",classification_report(ytrain,predictions))
```

the error log is :

```
Epoch 1/25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-176314eb8c1f> in <module>()
     25 model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
     26 model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer,metrics= metrics)
---> 27 model.fit(xtrain_w2v,ytrain,epochs=epochs,batch_size=batch_size,callbacks=callbacks,validation_data=(xvalid_w2v,yvalid))
     28 
     29 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:
```

Can you suggest to me something to do?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?